# How to mock Instant.now() in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, mockk

How can I mock `Instant.now()` using mockK?
This code throws error:

```
@Test
fun testStaticMock() {
  val instant = Instant.parse("2024-03-22T12:00:00.000Z")
  mockkStatic(Instant::class) {
    every { Instant.now() } returns instant
    val actual = Instant.now()
    assertEquals(instant, actual)
  }
}
```

`Missing mocked calls inside every { ... } block: make sure the object inside the block is a mock`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not really answering your question here, but that's because I think it is bad practice to mock an `Instant`. You should instead use a `Clock` and pass it as an argument to your service/function. You can call `Instant.now(clock)` to get an instant from the `Clock`. A `Clock` makes your code much more testable, because you can control it better from your tests.

In your production code, you can use a real clock with `Clock.system(ZoneId zone)`, `Clock.systemDefault()` or `Clock.systemUTC()`.

In your tests, you can create a fixed-clock with `Clock.fixed(Instant fixedInstant, ZoneId zone)`, and even make it tick with `Clock.tick`, `Clock.tickMinutes` or `Clock.tickSeconds`. This will make your tests more predictable, because they won't depend on the time they are run.

Comment: It is worth mentioning then if we only need to retrieve the `Instant`, then Java 17 introduced the `InstanceSource` as a "lighter" and better alternative to `Clock`. It is interface vs class, and also `Clock` is more complicated due to timezone handling.

Answer (score 0):

First, I would like to reiterate @marstran's answer. **You shouldn't mock this**, you should instead inject a `Clock` into your production classes, and inject a test clock during tests.

If you really really want to go the mock route, then read on.

---

Answering the exact question, the `every { ... }` line should be outside the `mockkStatic` block:

```kotlin
val instant = Instant.parse("2024-03-22T12:00:00.000Z")
mockkStatic(Instant::class)
every { Instant.now() } returns instant


val actual = Instant.now()
assertEquals(instant, actual)
```

However, beware: with JDK16+ you might have problems. Your exact example is even mentioned on [Mockk's website](https://mockk.io/doc/md/jdk16-access-exceptions.html) as a problematic one, that leads to this error:

```
java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2022-09-15T09:31:26.919Z' could not be parsed:
  Unable to make private static java.time.Instant java.time.Instant.create(long,int) accessible: 
  module java.base does not "opens java.time" to unnamed module @4501b7af
```

As a workaround, you will have to open modules for this to work (see the link above).

Comment: Interestingly after making these changes, I still see the same error as before. Anyways, I will go with the recommended approach of using a Clock.